# How to make a real-world application in VBA+Access '03: what is the best way to connect to a DB?

Tags: ms-access

First of all this is a question: "what is the best way to connect to a DB? " so don't delete it. thanks

I'm now facing a real problem at code organization when I connect to a DB with Access, when building forms. I'm coming from a MVC background and I don't see any simple way to do this. The DB connecting process is quite overkill for what I'm know right now and that's why I ask you guys if you know what are the best practices, or design patterns, for building real-world MS Access Forms that connects to a DB. (and of course reuse code, be DRY)
Are there any great frameworks to help my "difficult" life?

Comment: I've been developing Access applications professionally since 1996, so I really don't understand your question. You create your app, create the linked tables that point to your data, and that's it -- the forms/reports are bound, so there is no connection management. What were you thinking you were going to do?

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to use unbound forms or use some other form-to-data-connection methodology that is not native to MS Access. Access works best, generally speaking, if you use bound forms and connect your forms by filling out the RecordSource property with an SQL Statement. You can alternately connect to your data source using ADO Classic and simply set the forms RecordSet Property to your ADO Recordset but there is little or no good reason to do this.

Comment: I will explain to you how my "app" is: there is a search-text-box, and when you click the "search" button it must update a list-box. When you click on any of that list-box item another list-box updates. Then you can select your item on the 2º list and click on another button that will do something to that item. How I currently usa a DB: >INSERT/UPDATE: "CurrentDb.Execute myQuery"; >SELECT: 
"Public cnConnection As ADODB.connection;[...];
Dim rsRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
rsRecordset.Open search, cnConnection"; get the value: "rsRecordset.Fields(0).value"

Comment: That description of the app belongs in the question -- edit it to include it. But what you're describing is an unbound app. Secondly, within Access with ODBC linked tables, you should use DAO instead of ADO/OLEDB. Basically, you're still working with the wrong development paradigm. Build your app with point and click and then automate that with a sprinkling of necessary code. That's the Access way, and until you can do it that way, you're always going to be fighting against Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data resides outside Microsoft Access (e.g. in another database platform), you could use linked tables.  This would separate the interface of the Microsoft Forms from the actual data.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/link-tables-in-an-access-project-by-using-the-link-table-wizard-adp-HP003089371.aspx